# Magento Checkout Billing Section

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I came across this piece of code in billing.phtml

```
 var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
```

Is `address` is parameter to `getAddress()` method? or something else?

How to see the values of `address`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `address` is a param for `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::getAddressAction()`.

To see its value right on submission use a HTTP monitoring tool like Firebug, Fiddler, etc.

Or change the `getAddressAction()` method and write the value to a log file. For example like this:

```
public function getAddressAction()
{
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $addressId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('address', false);
    error_log('$addressId = ' . print_r($addressId, true), 3, '__my.log');
    // :
}
```